# Azure Function : How to see if a record exists in Table Storage

Tags: azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Note : this is for an Azure Function. The [normal C# links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet) on microsoft docs do not apply. It is for an Azure Function.

Scenario:

I need to have 1 entry only per Person, with the last date that this person logged in. This property gets updated every time.

Azure Functions still cannot do an [upsert](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/919)

Therefore I had to split my code into

1. Creating a new record.
2. [Updating an existing record.](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-update-delete-table-storage/)

I cannot simply run the update method for both creating and updating :

> error CS1061: 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and
>   no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type
>   'CloudTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

So at this point, I need to check if a item already exists, and then I need to call either the create or update function.

How do I use a Azure Function to query Table Storage to see if an item exists?

Comment: Are you using c# ? `.cs` or `.csx` file ? Please provide more information. what is the version of the azure storage table nuget package that you are using ? Btw you're disclaimer is wrong, the normal doc applies to azure function. Have you read about table binding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if entity exists, you can just accept it as input parameter and test for `null`:

```cs
[FunctionName("UpsertEntity")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route="test/{id}")] 
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    string id,
    [Table("Test", "default", "{id}")] MyEntity entity)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity != null ? "exists" : "not found");
}
```

You could do upsert with a combination of input and output parameters:

```cs
[FunctionName("UpsertEntity")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route="test/{id}")] 
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    string id,
    [Table("Test", "default", "{id}")] MyEntity entity,
    [Table("Test", "default", "{id}")] out MyEntity outEntity)
{
    outEntity = entity ?? new MyEntity { PartitionKey = "default", RowKey = id };
    outEntity.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
}
```